# how to override user agent CSS

Tags: html, css, user-agent

I want to have an unordered list without bullet next to it's items. I founded CSS property **list-style-type** and I set it to **none**. when I put this in html element it works fine:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li> item1 </li>
    <li> item2 </li>
</ul>
```

But when I put it in a seprate CSS file, it does not work because of a user agent property **list-style-type: disk;**

I try to override it using **!important** but again it is not overridden. this is an image of google chrome inspect element which shows the user agent rule is stroked, but the computed value for this property is the user agent value!

[image]

Update: the css file is linked correctly. I add another image which shows the user agent property is stroked, but it is still used as the final value:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the CSS-file isn't referenced properly. How do you include the CSS-file? Is the path to the file correct, or do you get a 404 for the CSS-file?

Comment: It seems working find to me see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/VN8b2/). You might search for a css reset.

Comment: Although from your screenshot I would think the oo.css is linked properly and the style also is set correctly... please show the css file and how you add the css file to your html file so we can see if maybe there is some mistake. By default user-agent styles should always be overwritten by any style defined, even without !important....

Comment: I notice from your image that you have a warning in your console (the red icon at the bottom right). Is that a 404 on the CSS-file we see perhaps?

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson: The path to the file is correct (as you can see in the image my file is oo.css). I tried to add another image which shows it better, but it seems Uploading is not available currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you are trying to apply the `list-style-type` property to a span-element, according to this selector `span.form-error`. That property is not valid for a `span` element, but should be applied directly to the `ul` in your case.

As an experiment, you could add this rule to your CSS-file, to see that this is the actual problem:

```
ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

If that works, then you could make your rule more specific by adding a class to your ul, and use that class for your css-selector.

Answer (score 1):

Even without `!important` the CSS should override the user agent. This problem is probably caused by not linking to your CSS properly in your HTML.

Also check out this [style reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). Including this in your documents will reduce browser inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

Is your stylesheet actually included on your page through the [`link` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element)?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyStylesheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

User agent stylesheets should never take precedence over your site's stylesheets. Furthermore, `!important`, as suggested by the other answer here, is bad practice and wouldn't be at all necessary here.

Edit: The other answer I referenced above was removed. The newer answer suggests using a "style reset" but that really wouldn't be required for this - you already know which property you're trying to override.